# Mechanism for calculating smooth trajectory?

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-core, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a wheelchair robot, and I have written by own path planner. My path planner gives a set of waypoints to reach the goal, each ~1m apart, and a path is re-planned every time there is something observed by Kinect. I have been sending these waypoints to move_base to get to these waypoints, treating them as a goal to move_base node. However, I realized that move_base is slow in adapting to a new goal when there is a goal already being pursued.

I just need a mechanism that computes a smooth trajectory given a two points (current position and the goal), by taking account of the current robot's velocity and position. I do not need obstacle avoidance, costmap update, recovery method and etc, which I presume is slowing down the move_base node. Is there a such node in ROS? I think base_local_planner is somehow publishing the velocity (cmd_vel topic) with a given plan, however I do not really have a plan but only two points.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42521/mechanism-for-calculating-smooth-trajectory?/) by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is not quite what you are looking for, but you can try to use **goal_passer** as your local planner, which is available in the [navigation_experimental](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_experimental) stack or **carrot_planner**. Both are simpler planners that may speed up your navigation. If they do not suit you, you can look at their codes and create your own. cheers

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on 2012-08-30**:
Hi, I checked out goal_passer, but the wiki page is empty. Do you know what it does? Right now it is just rotating in one place, with 0 linear velocity.

**Comment by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on 2012-08-30**:
Hi again. Instead of goal_passer, I used carrot_planner and like you said it is much faster than navfn. However, when I use carrot_planner it will move for sometime and stops, and continue moving. Do you know what might be causing this movement?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-09-01**:
take a look at the goal_passer code, i am not quite sure how it works, but i have used it several times. also try to give a goal very very close to the robot, for me it does not work if the goal is far away (do not know why: http://answers.ros.org/question/33926/problems-with-goalpasser-distance-to)